# Fitting a straight line to components of complex numbers

Tags: time-series, fitting

I have a strange problem that I'm not sure how to solve:

I have complex data points in a time series. The amplitude of these complex numbers in the time series forms a straight line, which I have fit for. But now what I want to do is *subtract* this fit from the data points. Except I have no idea how to do that since I have fit in amplitude space, and I have to subtract it from (real, imaginary) space.

Is there any way to do this, or am I completely misguided?

Comment: Can't you transform between the spaces?

Comment: Why do you want to subtract the fitted amplitude from the original data? This seems like subtracting apples from oranges. Essentially, you have two-dimensional original data, fit a model to the absolute values and then want to subtract the fitted one-dimensional values from the original two-dimensional values. (You could *scale* the original data by dividing by the fits.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa - Effectively I want to get rid of the ramp due to the straight line. I initially thought of subtraction, but if it's easier to go between the spaces via division that's great too! But if I divide the imaginary part by the fit, wouldn't that change the effective phase of the points?

Comment: The phase wouldn't change, since you would scale *both* the real and the imaginary part, and the phase depends only on the ratio between the two. Essentially, you would project a point in the complex plane onto the unit circle along the half-line from the origin through that point. (I still don't think I really understand what you are trying to achieve, though... maybe you want to edit your question to add a few more details.)